# How to get form-data from TcpClient

Tags: c#, webserver, tcpclient

I created a simple webserver that serves HTML files when you connect to it.

I created a simple form, now how come I get the form paramaters, I tried to keep reading from the request but I can't find it..

That's all I can read:
[image: Request Data from client]

The code I use to read from the client:

```
while(true) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for next request...");
    TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

    try 
    {
        string req = sr.ReadLine();

        for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
            string header = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(header);
        }


        string[] toks = req.Split(' ');
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Request Method: " + toks[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("Request File: " + toks[1]);
        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + toks[2]);
        Console.WriteLine("");
        string page = toks[1];
        //Serving files&catch comes here...
}
```

Comment: And the code...I know it's hard to believe, but, we are not magicians?

Comment: Im just reading from the client using a stream reader..

Comment: Post some code. We cannot help otherwise.

Comment: Added code now.